# Create jqueryMobile page dynamically based on the url

Tags: node.js, jquery-mobile, mobile, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am creating an application to get some experience in **jQuery Mobile** and **backbone**. I have made a "restful" API with **node.js** that handles the data I need. It works fine with all my static pages I made in index.html. But when I need to create a page with data from a certain `id` I am a bit lost.

For example when I want to display all items(/items) I have a `data-role=page` with `id` items that list all items, but when I need to go to a detailed page for each item (/items/1) **i want to create that details page whenever a user wants details on an item, in other words when a user visit the url spots#3 for example.**

Is this possible?

my router: the model gives me all data i want

```
Spoter.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        "":             "",
        "spot#:id":     "spotDetails" 

    },

    //Details on a certain spot with id
    spotDetails: function(id) {

        var spotDetailsContentDiv = Spoter.spotDetailsContent;
        spotDetailsContentDiv.empty();

        var spot = new Spoter.spotModel({id: id});
        spot.fetch({

            successCallback: function(data) {

                var spotDetailsView = new Spoter.spotDetailsView({

                    model: data
                });

                spotDetailsContentDiv.html(spotDetailsView.render().el);

            }

        });


    }

});
```

View:

```
Spoter.spotDetailsView = Backbone.View.extend({

    render:function () {

        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model));
        return this;
    }
});
```

Template with underscore

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-inset="true">
        <li>
            <a href="#">
            <h1><%= this.model.name %></h1>
            <p><%= this.model.description %></p>
            </a>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you give a few more details on exactly which part isn't working?  A couple of things look odd at a glance:  the success callback passed to `fetch()` should be called `success` not `successCallback`, and ideally you shouldn't be setting the `html()` value of that div in the model (although that won't actually break the app).

Comment: I managed to solve it by completely turning off jQuery Mobiles routing functions and let backbone handel all that.